# Double-click to jump between top and bottom of table column

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change this sub so that double-clicking the same cell jumps between the top and bottom of the table column?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Jump" Then
        Cancel = True
        Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Same cell`? One specific cell? One cell on the table? Or any cell? You have not given us any criteria there.

Comment: `If ActiveCell.Value = "Jump" Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Value = "Jump" Then
        Cancel = True
        If Target.Row < 10 Then
            Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Select
        Else
            Cells(1, 1).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit: if you just want to toggle the direction then:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Static GoUp As Boolean
    If Target.Value = "Jump" Then
        Cancel = True
        If GoUp  Then
            Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Select
        Else
            Cells(3, 1).Select 'first cell below any frozen rows at the top
        End If
        GoUp = Not GoUp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Double-clicking still always jumps to the bottom.

Comment: Well where is the other "Jump" cell ? - I was assuming you had another one at the bottom of your table...  If not then do you have some rows frozen at the top of the sheet or ???

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have the top row frozen; there is only one "Jump" cell.